# Python overriding default attribute assignment

Tags: python-3.x

for a specific framework i work with, i need to define object attributes as special classes, for example, instead of writing this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_int = 2
```

i would need to write:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_int = SpecialIntWrapper(name = "some_int", value = 2)
```

I would like to somehow override operators/methods so that typing the first code (self.some_int = 2) will call SpecialIntWrapper behind the scenes, with the attribute name and value.

is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are two ways - via a `@property` decorator (preferable unless you want to affect arbitrary names)

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_int = 2

    # if you know the name of the property define it as a property - a getter
    @property
    def some_int(self):
        return self._some_int

    # and a setter
    @some_int.setter
    def some_int(self, value):
        self._some_int = SpecialIntWrapper("some_int", value)
```

or overloading the `__setattr__` magic method

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_int = 2

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # in general if you dont know the names of the properties 
        # beforehand you can somehow filter them here
        if name == "some_int":
            super().__setattr__(name, SpecialIntWrapper(name=name, value=value))
        else:
            # to use the setattr in a default way, just call it via super(Python 3)
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

either way the `some_int` will be initialized to the `SpecialIntWrapper` instance

```
>>>print(MyClass().some_int)
<__main__.SpecialIntWrapper object at 0x03721810>
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to put both techniques in the same example, since you should only use one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
class SpecialIntWrapper:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        pass


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_int = 3

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'some_int':
            self.__dict__[key] = SpecialIntWrapper(key, value)
        else:
            self.__dict__[key] = value

print(MyClass().some_int)
# >>> <__main__.SpecialIntWrapper object at 0x1076f1748>
```